# java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling combination for invocation context

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, dto

I have an application consisted of 3 layers: **DB**, **back-end** containing EJBs (run separately on Wildfly EJB container) and **Front-End** an EJB client (run separately on Tomcat). The communication between front-end and back-end is done by DTOs (Data Transfer Object). Everything was working fine until I added a new map field in one of the DTOs:

```
public class xxxDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5811694947383586010L;

    // simple fields like String, Integer, etc. go here
    private Map<Language, yyyNameDTO> NameDetailsMap;

    .....
}
```

As soon as I added the map field, the EJB method call on `xxxDTO` from the client gave the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:app, moduleName:app-ejb, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@2d3f6ba3
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:749) ~[jboss-ejb-client-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:116) ~[jboss-ejb-client-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186) ~[jboss-ejb-client-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.retryRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:211) ~[jboss-ejb-client-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:256) ~[jboss-ejb-client-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:265) ~[jboss-ejb-client-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:198) ~[jboss-ejb-client-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181) ~[jboss-ejb-client-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144) ~[jboss-ejb-client-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.registerTaxpayer(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptorUtils.invokeRemoteMethod(RmiClientInterceptorUtils.java:71) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.doInvoke(SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.invokeInContext(AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:140) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.invoke(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:189) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.registerTaxpayer(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

When I remove the map field, or set that field to `null` the EJB receiver becomes available and everything works fine, but if the map field has a value other than `null`, the EJB receiver becomes unavailable.

I tried to solve it by changing the `SerialVersionUID` (thinking that it might be a serialization and versioning issue) but with no result.

**The questions are:**

- Why does the map field cause in throwing the exception?
- How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the issue.
Foolish mistake: I forgot to implement `Serializable` interface and put a `serialVersionUID` for my `yyyNameDTO` newly added DTO class.